# PHP shell_exec / passthru showing output different from actual shell output

Tags: php, shell, shell-exec, passthru

I am trying to display the output of a shell command using PHP's `passthru` function. I am getting an extra `[0;32m` where the actual shell output has a green line and am also getting an extra `[m` at the beginning of few other lines.

**What do I need to do to get a PHP output without these additional characters?**

My PHP command is:

```
passthru('/var/www/cCompiledScript');
```

Comment: Where did you get `cCompiledScript`? It may have a flag to turn off color output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what `cCompiledScript` is, but clearly it is outputing ANSI escape sequences to generate color on the terminal. It may have a command line flag or environment variable that you can set to disable color output. If you wrote `cCompiledScript` you could add a flag to disable color.  Otherwise you will have to strip out the color codes:

```
passthru('/var/www/cCompiledScript | sed "s/\x1B\[\([0-9]\{1,2\}\(;[0-9]\{1,2\}\)\?\)\?[mGK]//g"');
```

The `sed` command above is from [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/111936) on the [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: cCompiledScript is a wrapper.c script.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know what that is.